# How to extract error descriptions from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

I have this batch script:

```
@echo off
set server_list=C:\temp\servers.txt
set cab=E:\PHC\wsusscn2.cab
set sass=E:\PHC\SASS\sass.exe
erase c:\sass\error.log
for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%i in (%server_list%) do (
    echo %%i
    xcopy %cab% \\%%j\c$\sass /Y || echo %%i: ?error description (invalid drive specification, Access denied etc)? >> c:\sass\error.log
    xcopy %sass% \\%%j\c$\sass /Y || echo %%i: ?error description (invalid drive specification, Access denied etc)? >> c:\sass\error.log
    wmic /node:%%j PROCESS CALL CREATE "cmd /c c:\sass\sass.exe -i c:\sass\wsusscn2.cab -o c:\sass\%%i.csv" || echo %%i: ?error description (RPC server not available etc)? >> c:\sass\error.log
    )
pause`
```

The script works fine, problem is, I can't get the error descriptions to the error.log file (between the question marks). It would help greatly, if I knew, why exactly the operation was unsuccessful. I tried the following:

```
echo %%i: cab file copy failed - %ERRORLEVEL%
```

But it always results in errorlevel 0 (obviously errorlevel of the echo command). I tried several ways to store the errorlevel to a variable, but always unsuccessfully. Furthermore, errorlevel only gives me partially what I want, not the descriptions, but just type of error.

The file Servers.txt contains hostnames of servers in one column, and their IPs in the second column.

How can I extract the error descriptions?

Comment: have you tried to catch STDERR with `2>>errorlog.txt`?

Comment: Looks like it works, thanks. Strangely, it first did not work in the morning, but in the afternoon, without any modification of the file, it did work fine :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by using STDERR. This is working form of the questioned lines:

```
xcopy %cab% \\%%j\c$\sass /Y 2>> C:\SASS\error.log
xcopy %sass% \\%%j\c$\sass /Y 2>> C:\SASS\error.log
wmic /node:%%j PROCESS CALL CREATE "cmd /c c:\sass\sass.exe -i c:\sass\wsusscn2.cab -o c:\sass\%%i.csv" 2>> C:\SASS\error.log
```

This code types precisely what I need to the error.log file. Since this solution does not state the hostname of the server, I had to add these lines to the beginning of the loop:

```
echo ----------- >> C:\SASS\error.log
echo %%i >> C:\SASS\error.log
```